# How do I make sure that the button is checked?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

The assignment is a basic voting system of picking between 3 people or 4th button is a "decline to answer"

I keep getting errors such as "Cannot find symbol"

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Vote
{
    JLabel  label;

    public static void main (String[] args)

    {
        Vote sr = new Vote();
    }

    public Vote ()
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Please Choose your next President:");
        JRadioButton one = new JRadioButton("Name 1");
        JRadioButton two = new JRadioButton("Name 2");
        JRadioButton three = new JRadioButton("Name 3");
        JRadioButton four = new JRadioButton("I decline to answer");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(one);
        panel.add(two);
        panel.add(three);
        panel.add(four);

        ButtonGroup but = new ButtonGroup();

        but.add(one);
        but.add(two);
        but.add(three);
        but.add(four);

        one.addActionListener(new MyAction());
        two.addActionListener(new MyAction());
        three.addActionListener(new MyAction());
        four.addActionListener(new MyAction());

        label = new JLabel("Please Select a Canidate for President ");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public class MyAction implements ActionListener

    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)

        {
            if (jRadioButton.isSelected())
            {
                label.setText(e.getActionCommand());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected " +

                e.getActionCommand()
                        + " as the new President. Thank you for voting.");
            }
            else
            {
                label.setText(e.getActionCommand());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected " +

                e.getActionCommand() + " Thank you for voting.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basic functions is to pick a name from 4 available radio buttons and upon selection of any buttons, a new windows comes up saying thank you for voting.

I would like to have different responses depending on the radio button pressed, so if a button pressed saying "I declined to answer" a proper response would be towards it.

Please check my *If* statement because i think where most of the errors are coming from and from a part of `.isSelected` .

Comment: It would help if you show us where you get the error (at which line)

Comment: @msrd0 at if statement

Answer (score 2):

```
if(jRadioButton.isSelected())
```

jRadioButton here is not defined.

You would want to get the source that triggered the event (i.e. one, two, three or four):

```
if(((JRadioButton)e.getSource()).isSelected())
```

This gets the object that triggered the event, casts it as a JRadioButton, and checks if that radio button is selected.

That should at least get rid of your "Cannot find symbol" error.

Comment: this help however how do i form the if statement directly towards the button 4?

Comment: Check the answer by kklys, that's what I would have recommended. I'm not 100% sure, but getActionCommand might return the text in your JRadioButton, so you could theoretically use that and check against the known text of "I decline to answer". If that doesn't work you will have to use setActionCommand as outlined in the other answer.

Comment: Yes, by default `getActionCommand()` will return "I decline to answer", but it will be good idea to set action command to something more useful. The text may be changed in the future and then you would have to change `if` statement, which is not a good idea.

Comment: @kklys I agree, that is definitely a safer approach. Alternatively, a const could be defined if declining to answer is always an option and it can be checked against the constant. Whether you use the default setActionCommand() value or set your own, having a constant would be best to safeguard against changing a value and forgetting to update all the references to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have no object named `jRadioButton`.
try changing

```
jRadioButton.isSelected()
```

to

```
((JRadioButton)e.getSource()).isSelected()
```

Also if you want to check if **4th** `JRadioButton` was selected, then do the following:

```
four.setActionCommand("fourth");
```

and then in `if` statement

```
if ("fourth".equals(e.getActionCommand()) && ((JRadioButton)e.getSource()).isSelected())
```

it will check if action command maches fourth radio button and if it is selected